# Passenger using Ruby system version instead of Ruby from RVM

Tags: rvm, passenger, production-environment, ruby-1.9.3, mod-rails

I'm using RVM (1.19), Passenger (3.0.19), Apache on a Debian environment.

I tried update the ruby version from 1.8.7 to 1.9.3 using RVM. The following steps were executed:

- rvm install 1.9.3
- rvm rvmrc to .ruby-version (in my Rails app folder)
- rvm use 1.9.3 & gem install passenger & rvm passenger-install-apache2-module (to install passenger and apache2-module in my 1.9.3 environment)
- updated 'mod_rails.load' file in '/etc/apache2/mods-available/':

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/passenger-3.0.19
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ruby
```

- And finally, I restarted the apache server.

After all, my application is still using Ruby 1.8.7 and Passenger is getting gems from '/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/'. So I guess Passenger is ignoring the configuration in mod_rails.load.

Does anyone know how resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

what does `ruby -v` output?

if it is `1.8.7` try `rvm use 1.9.3` and be sure that 1.9.3 is set as the default.

`rvm default 1.9.3`

and that your `.rvmrc` is sourced in your `.bash_profile` something like:

```
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`
```

also what does `which rvm` return?  that should be the start of file path you use to load gems from. its normally something like `/Users/local/.rvm`